# ANDROID: Saving User Data For Itemized ListView in Another Activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I'm working on an app that allows you to rate Pro Golfers and type what you think the pros and cons of this particular Golfer is. There is an EditText which saves the String data to an Arraylist, and a Ratingbar which saves int values to it's own Arraylist.

I would like to allow the user to input their data, and then on another activity, have buttons or a view of some kind that allows the user to tap and open one of their finalized sessions for viewing. How can this be done?

Comment: store the information in the application (if it makes sense) and pass that information to the following activity

Comment: How might one go about storing Arraylists? Is it possible with SQLite? Will the data show up every time the user launches the app? And how might one go about itemizing each session for the user into a ListView in another activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, depending on how long you need to keep information, and how complicated you want to get with it. If you just want to pass this one `ArrayList` this one time, then add it to the intent when you start the new activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, someOtherActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("values",myList);
```

and then in `onCreate` of the new activity, retrieve the data:

```
myList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("values");
// Do stuff
```

If you have one set of data that you want to keep even when the user restarts their phone, then you could use `SharedPreferences`, which is pretty easy. You can read more on that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

If you have multiple sets of data, and those data are guaranteed to remain small, performance is not an issue, and you are willing to load the whole data set into memory every time you interact with it, then you could save it to a flat file either internally or on the SD card. More on that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

If you have multiple sets of data, and the above criteria are not true, then you'll probably want to store it in a database. There are two basic approaches to this: Directly interfacing with a SQLite database, or building a content provider. The former is easier to get set up, but difficult to maintain. The latter is significantly more annoying to get working right, but it is easier to maintain, and comes with significant advantages like easy integration with `listviews` and the ability to share that data with other apps. Either way these are not trivial problems and I advise you look at the developer guides for [databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) and [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and looking up tutorials on both. Implementing them is much more suitable to blog posts or chapters in a textbook than a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response The thing I'm trying to figure out is, once I've saved the data, how to update a listview in another activity with it. The user gives a name to this session, then adds data during the session via edittexts. I want to find a way to make it so each time the user enters a session title, the listview updates in the other activity with the session name, and then when the user navigates to the listview activity they can tap the view and see their inputed data almost like a notepad app. I would like this to repeat and further populate the listview each time a new session saves

Comment: The best way to do that, thinking in the long term, would be to create a content provider. Your listview could then populate using a cursor that gets data from that content provider, and if you do everything right, that cursor will be updated, and the listview along with it, immediately when new data is entered into the content provider. But be warned, proper implementation of a content provider is not trivial. Look at many tutorials, ask questions, and consider taking Coursera's Programming Cloud Services for Android course which has a section on Content Providers

Comment: Ok cool, I'll look into Content Providers thoroughly, I guess SQLite isn't ideal then?

Comment: Content Providers are a means of interacting with another storage medium, most commonly SQLite. The problem with using SQLite directly is, as you brought up, updating views when the data changes. I haven't found a great way to do that cleanly. But if you're using a Content Provider, Android does most of that for you. Also, I think that if you intend to do more Android development in the future, understanding Content Providers will be very useful to you.